# Upload flutter project to GitHub

Tags: flutter, github

**I have a flutter project created in android studio.**
I want to upload it to GitHub so that I can share it and remotely for downloading on other system. I am new to GitHub. How I can upload my codes? Keep in mind that I have not created a repository yet. How can I add it so that push pull function also work properly??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will create a repository and then you will follow the instructions given [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line)

I would suggest you also to watch a video in youtube there are plenty of them

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions for you that are easy to do for most users

**Option 1:** your home page click `New` button and type in the repository name, click on `Upload existing file` and select your files you want to upload

**Option 2:** You could also use the github desktop app [found here](https://desktop.github.com/) and upload folder directly

YouTube is also a great place if you want to learn about git and github